# ActiveRecord where method returns empty array

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I recently upgraded my Rails project to 5 and have found that whenever I do something like:

`User.where(boolProperty: true)` it always returns empty. However if I do `User.where.not(boolProperty: false)` I get the correct response.

Does anyone know why this broke? It's specific for filtering by boolean attributes.

I'm using **Sqlite3**, here are the SQL statements generated by both

User.where(deactivated: false).to_sql :

`SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."deactivated" = 0`

User.where.not(deactivated: true).to_sql:

`SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."deactivated" != 1`

Comment: What database flavor? Can you post the SQL that is generated by both?

Comment: Updated the post with both pieces of info

Comment: It appears that my SQLIte3 is saving false values as "f" instead of 0...

Comment: I think ActiveRecord switched to proper SQLite booleans (i.e. MySQL-style `1` and `0`) at some point. AFAIK it used to use `'t'` and `'f'` (which are properly converted to real booleans in PostgreSQL).

Comment: ^ I think right now it's using `1` for true and `f` for false. (Based on the 2 SQL statements above)

Comment: Can you try running `User.all.pluck(:deactivated)` and see if it is returning any other value like `nil` apart from `0` and `1`. This will be helpful in debugging the problem.

Comment: Unrelated but not, using the same db for development and production will save you many headaches. Postgres and mysql are safe choices.

Comment: You should look at the database and the data type for that column `!= 1` does not necessarily mean `=0` in some databases (SQLite may be one of them). I remember when I used to work on MSAccess Databases they used bit flags which could be 1, 0, or -1 which causes a lot of confusion when you want a boolean value but have 3 options.

Comment: @engineersmnky Things are even stranger in SQLite: columns don't really have types, values do. So you can put `0` and `'t'` in the same column and they'll stay as `0` and `'t'` even if the column itself is marked as `real`.

Comment: @muistooshort ouch that's rough. I've never used SQLite but that seems like a debugging nightmare

Comment: @engineersmnky Yeah, it can be. But it is super-handy when you need an embedded SQL database or an SQL-database-in-a-single-file.